# Generating list of lists of random numbers with lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm experimenting with Genetic Algorithms using Lisp,
I want to generate a list of lists that contains five random numbers.

I can generate that list but all the sub-lists are composed of the same random numbers and that is because I'm not sure I'm managing the "random state" properly.

Can anyone give me an hint?

here is the code:

```
(setf *random-state* (make-random-state t))    
(defun random_in 
      (min max) 

      (+ (random (+ (- max min) 1) *random-state*) min))

    (defun create_chromosome
      (min max) 
      (list (random_in min max) (random_in min max) (random_in min max) (random_in min max) (random_in min max)))

    (defun create_population
      (individuals min max)
        (make-list individuals :initial-element (create_chromosome min max)))



    (write (create_population 3 10 100))
```

The output of this program is:

```
((54 51 85 61 44) (54 51 85 61 44) (54 51 85 61 44))
```

but I want each list composed by different random numbers.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I've updated removing (setf *random-state ...) from "random_in" and putting it as the first line of the program but the problem is the same...

Comment: Would you care to use standard formatting and naming conventions?

Comment: @DavideCremona Svante go it.  You're only calling `create_chromosome` once, and then repeating that value.  That's how `make-list` works. It's a function, and so `(create_chromosome min max)` is just a regular argument expression which gets evaluated once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `:initial-element` with `make-list`, that element is created only once.

One way to achieve what you want:

```
(loop :repeat individuals
      :collect (create-chromosome min max))
```

Comment: Not to mention that `create_chromosome` itself could benefit from the same thing: `(loop repeat 6 collect (random_in min max))`